# Multipart sms not visible in the SMS app

Tags: java, android, sms

I know I can send multipart SMS with **sendMultipartTextMessage** and I can send SMS without writing it to the SMS provider with **sendTextMessageWithoutPersisting** but how to do both? I want to send multipart SMS that will not be visible in the SMS app

Comment: what have you tried till now, show us some code

Comment: "how to do both?" - Be the user's currently selected default messaging app. It's responsible for writing it's own outgoing messages. Apart from that, you can't, pretty much. The `sendTextMessageWithoutPersisting()` method was just added in P - presumably as a convenience for OTP/registration texts and the like - so you can't even do it with a single-part message until then, unless you're the default.

Comment: Actually, now that I look more closely, you won't be able to use that method anyway, as it requires the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission, and is "Intended for internal carrier use only". So, yeah, be the default, or you can't prevent any of your outgoing text messages from being written.